# Why is sin slower in webassembly than in java script?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I have some very simple benchmark that is run via Catch2, and compiled with -O3 using `emscripten 3.1.37`:

```cpp
    BENCHMARK("cpp sin only")
    {
        double sum = 1.0;
        for (int t = 0; t < 2000000; ++t) {
            sum += sin(double(t));
        }
        return sum;
    };

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    BENCHMARK("js sin only")
    {
        EM_ASM_DOUBLE({
            let sum = 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
                sum = sum + Math.sin(i);
            }
            return sum;
        });
    };
#endif
```

I would expect, that there wouldn't be a large difference between JavaScript and WebAssembly, but there is:

```
chrome:
benchmark name                       samples       iterations    est run time
                                     mean          low mean      high mean
                                     std dev       low std dev   high std dev
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cpp sin only                                   100             1     7.93775 s 
                                        79.3856 ms     79.147 ms    79.7195 ms 
                                        1.43061 ms    1.10437 ms    1.97222 ms 
                                                                               
js sin only                                    100             1     2.21506 s 
                                        22.1354 ms    22.0064 ms       22.3 ms 
                                        742.138 us    614.746 us    901.128 us
```

Native, compiled with `GCC 12.3.0`, i get 24.2ms.

- To my understanding, JavaScript uses double precision floats for all numbers. So the comparison should be fair. When using float in the C++ version, it gets to 12ms in chrome, but that is still slower (and less precise). FF sits at around 30ms.
- <del>Maybe JavaScript uses a less precise, but faster implementation of sin and sqrt? Adding `-fast-math` doesn't increase performance for double. Float with fast-math in chrome becomes as fast as JavaScript, in FF it's still at around 30ms.</del>
- Is it, that WebAssembly isn't given as much time in the optimiser? That could explain, why it's so much slower in FF. But shouldn't emscripten take care of most of the optimisation?
- Could it be some sort of protection against meltdown/spectre?

**Update** (I ran several additional benchmarks on a request in the comments):

- g++12 is a bit faster than clang15, but that's within 10%
- performance of sqrt is almost equal between the versions (before there was a sqrt and a sin in the example)
- most of the time is spent in sin.
- **increasing the iteration count to 2 millions makes JS about 4x faster. increasing it to 5 millions increases the lead to 10x. JS is still about the same speed as C++ native.**
- note that the benchmark is execute 100 times by Catch2. The runtime of above code is around 1s.
- I verified that it's not as simple as JS using float. The webassembly c++ computation matches the JS result exactly.
- using 123456789042+1000000 increased the runtime by about 3-4x on gcc, clang native, webassembly c++ and js (the relative performance webassembly vs js stayed about the same).
- reference, this is the code i used: https://pastebin.com/Mu2barB6 and here are the results for chrome: https://pastebin.com/Hbte7yRj

**update 2:**

After [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77989813/why-is-sin-slower-in-webassembly-than-in-java-script/78128153?noredirect=1#comment137937888_78128153) by user21489919, I [reported the issue to emscripten](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/21660).

Comment: The GCC stack and LLVM ones can produce very different codes. Thus, the performance can also be very different. Especially, I expect the `sin` implementation not to behave the same performance-wise. What do you get if you compile the code with Clang the way you do in GCC?

Comment: This loop use both a simple `sqrt` call and a complex `sin` one. It would be interesting to split this in two benchmark to see whether it happens only with the `sqrt` or not. I expect `sin` to be the culprit of the performance gap here. Note that modern x86-64 CPUs have a fast `sqrtsd` instruction to compute that in-silico and mainstream compilers generally use it. There is no such an instruction for `sin` though, so it is computed within software library functions (especially `libm`) using various approaches.

Comment: *"WebAssembly isn't given as much time in the optimiser?"* You can check that by increasing the duration of the benchmark. dozens of ms is clearly too short for a benchmark. Frequency scaling can cause huge bias, not to mention scheduling and start-up overheads. Please consider trying something lasting at least few seconds to be safe (for all implementations).

Comment: *"Maybe JavaScript uses a less precise"* I do not think so but you can check the accuracy of the result. I do not expect JS to compute things in simple-precision but JITs can do crazy optimizations these days. Besides, `t` is small enough so to be contained in a simple-precision value. You can change your benchmark so double-precision is mandatory to get good results : start `t` to `123456789042` and stop it to `123456789042+1000000` so to avoid such an optimization (too big to be correctly represented in simple-precision, but fine for double-precision) and check the accuracy of the result.

Comment: thanks for the comment!
i'm on a different machine now, and i increased the iteration count to 2 million. catch2 is running the benchmark 100 times, total runtime per case is now at 2.3s for js in the above code.

Comment: 1. i ran several benchmarks now (see below). g++12 is a bit faster than clang15, but that's within 10% 2. you are right. performance of sqrt is almost equal and most of the time is spent in sin. 3. as said, i increased the iteration count, but even before it was running for ~1s. increasing it further to 5 million gives JS a larger advantage of almost 10x.

Comment: 4. using 123456789042+1000000 increased the runtime by about 3-4x on gcc and clang native, webassembly c++ and js (the relative performance webassembly vs js stayed about the same). 5. i'll try to check the accuracy, but with this many iterations, i think the numerical error will be insane in all cases.

for reference, this is the code i used: https://pastebin.com/Mu2barB6

Comment: Oh, and increasing the iteration count to 2 million also increased the ratio webassembly / js from 1.5 to about 4x.

Comment: Now I did compare the results, and they are exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. It is certainly better to put that in an update rather than comments (for visibility, for clarifications, and possibly future readers).

Comment: Note that for the `123456789042+...` that the variable needs to be a 64-bit integer. `int` is a 32-bit integer on most platform (and default integers are `int` in C/C++ AFAIK). Otherwise, overflow will generate wrong results and the resulting number can be negative possibly impacting the branch prediction (and so performance). Results must be always checked to avoid comparing things that should not be compared.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean in your last comment. New results conflit with previous ones?

Comment: you are right. I edited the question. thanks for the hint :)
yes, i changed to int64. and no, no conflicting results. only i verified that the numerical result of webassembly and JS is equal.

Answer (score -1):

you might double check (ha!) that the long double version of sin() is not being invoked for some reason.  It's not obvious why it would be from your code sample, but c++ std  provides long double (128 bit in clang) versions of sin().

You could be double double sure that regular double is used by using .c instead of .cpp and #include <math.h>.

Comment: as mentioned in the question, the numerical results of c++ and js are equal. also this shouldn't happen since i'm giving normal double to std::sin.

Comment: I added a sin test to my wasm runtime library -- you can run the test at the following link - it is basically the same speed as Javascript.  That is because in my runtime I do acutally call the Javascript sin function from C.   see test at https://twiddlingbits.dev/examples/dist/tests/index.html

this is part of my tiny-wasm-runtime - https://github.com/twiddlingbits/tiny-wasm-runtime

Comment: interesting. in chrome on linux, the js only version is still a bit faster (~10%). But that we can explain by the calling overhead. On FF, the c++ version takes about half the time (which we can explain by js being slower in FF). All that would mean, that the slowness is within emscripten. thanks for that info!

btw: you are overwriting the sum in https://github.com/twiddlingbits/tiny-wasm-runtime/blob/main/examples/tests/index.html, so technically the test is wrong :)

Comment: @Adam I think since cpp23 you are always using the long double version of sin, can you test if using an older compiler that doesn't support it improves it? Try gcc 4.8.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin